# php-fpm status page does not display info about Idle processes

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php7

I have PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.3 running on my machine. Webserver is Nginx and is using FastCGI (php-fpm). I have setup two php-fpm status pages - one for the www pool of the php-fpm 5.6 and one for the www pool of the php-fpm 7.3.

The status page for version 5.6 is working correctly and gives desired output:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      static
start time:           29/Apr/2021:17:12:19 +0200
start since:          2870
accepted conn:        154
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     1
listen queue len:     128
idle processes:       4
active processes:     1
total processes:      5
max active processes: 2
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0

************************
pid:                  9209
state:                Idle
start time:           29/Apr/2021:17:12:19 +0200
start since:          2870
requests:             32
request duration:     331468
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php?q=test-page
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /data/www56/test/index.php
last request cpu:     48.27
last request memory:  26214400

************************
pid:                  9214
state:                Running
start time:           29/Apr/2021:17:12:19 +0200
start since:          2870
requests:             31
request duration:     107
request method:       GET
request URI:          /php56_status?full
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /data/www56/test/php56_status
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0
```

On the other hand, the status page for the version 7.3 has some weird behavior - request information (such as Method, URI, or script) are not displayed on **Idle** processes. These information are displayed only on **Running** processes on this php-fpm 7.3 pool:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      static
start time:           29/Apr/2021:17:41:56 +0200
start since:          1062
accepted conn:        45
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     1
listen queue len:     128
idle processes:       4
active processes:     1
total processes:      5
max active processes: 2
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0

************************
pid:                  9003
state:                Idle
start time:           29/Apr/2021:17:41:56 +0200
start since:          1062
requests:             9
request duration:     201048
request method:       -
request URI:          -
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               -
last request cpu:     19.90
last request memory:  4194304

************************
pid:                  9006
state:                Running
start time:           29/Apr/2021:17:41:56 +0200
start since:          1062
requests:             8
request duration:     140
request method:       GET
request URI:          /php73_status?full
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /data/www73/test/php73_status
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0
```

Nginx configuration in the same for both status pages:

```
#php5.6
location /php56_status {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
}

#php7.3
location /php73_status {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
}
```

Pools configurations are the same (default www.conf) and php-fpm configurations are the same (default php-fpm.conf) on both. The `fastcgi_params` file content:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
#fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https if_not_empty;
```

It is a little bit useless when I cannot access information about processes that ended (as it was possible in php-fpm 5.6). It is possible to display these information about Idle workers and their last script processed also in php-fpm 7.3? Or what have I wrong or missing here, that it is not working correctly?

Thank you!